# Use File.readlines to read line from separate Ruby file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have only two files inside one folder.

"seed.rb", which contains the seed data:

```
Jones,James
Williams,Violet
Walton,Briggs
```

"code.rb", which contains the code:

```
require_relative 'seed'

class TransferInformation
  def read_seed_data_from_file(filename)
    File.readlines(filename).each do |line|
      puts line
    end
  end
end

read_seed_data_from_file(seed)
```

In the console, I ran `ruby code.rb`.

The error I am getting now is "unexpected end-of-input for line 3 in seed.rb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"seed.rb" is not a Ruby file. Do not `require` (or `require_relative`) non-Ruby files. Just remove your `require_relative`.

I also suggest renaming "seed.rb" to something less deceptive, such as "seed.csv" (the usual extension for a [comma-separated values file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)).

Comment: when i take out require_relative and change seed.rb to seed.csv and then run ruby code.rb in the console, i now get -- undefined local variable or method 'seed'.

Comment: `read_seed_data_from_file("seed.cvs")`. `seed` would be a variable, and it is, as the error says, undefined.

Comment: awesome. thank you. and then i run this  `ruby -r "./code.rb" -e "TransferInformation.new.read_seed_data_from_file('seed.csv')"`  from the command line and it works great.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class, which makes working with CSV documents easier (unless you're just practicing your file reading skills).

Answer (score 2):

First, please understand that there is a standard for CSV files. It's often ignored by people who attempt to roll their own code to read and write it, but the standard remains. And, by using the pre-built wheels, like [the CSV class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) that comes with Ruby, your odds of generating correct CSV data goes way up, as does your odds of reading it.

The documentation has examples showing how to read and write CSV data, from files and from strings, so that's the starting point. Reading rows line-by-line from a file looks like:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

so to read your data:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("test.csv") do |row|
  puts row.reverse.join(' ')
end
```

Running it outputs:

```
James Jones
Violet Williams
Briggs Walton
```

You want to read CSV line-by-line most of the time because you are only concerned with a single line. Database dumps are often in CSV format, and trying to `read` the entire dump file of a huge database all at once ("slurping") can take your program down.

Now, some comments about your code:

- `TransferInformation` is not a good name for a class. A class should be a thing, like "IncomingData", "Data" or "UserNames" or "Names". Methods are actions or verbs.
- You can't say

  ```
  read_seed_data_from_file(seed)
  ```

  because that method is part of the TransferInformation class. You need to create an instance of the class, then you can call the method:

  ```
  ta = TransferInformation.new
  ta.read_seed_data_from_file('test.csv')
  ```

That looks about right, but hasn't been tested.